# Cucumber test: click on a specific button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara

I am a beginner to cucumber. I am trying to write a test to click a button. Here is my code

```
 </div >
    <%= link_to like_user_user_path(user),:class => 'users-button like-button', :id => 'like1', :method => :post do %>
      <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up hvr-bounce-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <% end %>
```

How can I write code to test when I click to specific button like this?

Answer (score 0):

Technically what you're showing is a link that is styled to look like a button, so it will not work with Capybaras `click_button`.  Because of that you need to use `#click_link`, `#click_link_or_button`, or just find the element some other way and call `#click` on it.  As a full cucumber step that could be written something like

```
When /I click on the "(.+)" link/ do |locator|
  page.click_link locator
end
```

and then called like

```
When I click on the "like1" link
```

Another option would be to do something like

```
When /I like the user/ do
  find(:css, 'a span.fa-thumbs-up').click
end
```

Comment: @ĐỗHuy you're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer so the question gets marked as answered